# Integration of Force to obtain Potential Energy

Tags: integration

Given that for a force $F$,
$F=- \frac{GMm}{r^2} + \frac{Am c^2 r}{3}$, 
where A and M are constant, and the potential energy $V$, where 
$V= - \int Fdr$, 
would I be correct in saying that 
$V=- \frac{A c^2 m r^2}{6} + \frac{GMm}{r}$. 
I did try the physics SE for this, but no joy. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want? You want to verify $V=-\int F dr = - \frac{A c^2 m r^2}{6} + \frac{GMm}{r}$?

Comment: Yes, as I'm not sure of myself

Comment: Please specify the variables. Because if you integrate F over $r$, V will clearly not depend on $r$.

Comment: F is force exerted on a galaxy, G is the constant G in physics, M is constant, m is the mass of the galaxy, r is the distance of the galaxy, and A is constant. Oh, and c is just c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given:
>
> $$\text{F}=\frac{\text{A}\text{m}\text{c}^2\text{r}}{3}-\frac{\text{G}\text{M}\text{m}}{\text{r}^2}$$

---

So:

$$\text{V}=-\int\text{F}\space\text{d}\text{r}=-\int\left[\frac{\text{A}\text{m}\text{c}^2\text{r}}{3}-\frac{\text{G}\text{M}\text{m}}{\text{r}^2}\right]\space\text{d}\text{r}=$$
$$\int\frac{\text{G}\text{M}\text{m}}{\text{r}^2}\space\text{d}\text{r}-\int\frac{\text{A}\text{m}\text{c}^2\text{r}}{3}\space\text{d}\text{r}=$$
$$\text{G}\text{M}\text{m}\int\frac{1}{\text{r}^2}\space\text{d}\text{r}-\frac{\text{A}\text{m}\text{c}^2}{3}\int\text{r}\space\text{d}\text{r}=$$
$$\text{G}\text{M}\text{m}\cdot-\frac{1}{\text{r}}-\frac{\text{A}\text{m}\text{c}^2}{3}\cdot\frac{\text{r}^2}{2}+\text{K}=$$
$$-\frac{\text{G}\text{M}\text{m}}{\text{r}}-\frac{\text{A}\text{m}\text{c}^2\text{r}^2}{6}+\text{K}$$

So, we get that:

$$\text{V}=-\int\text{F}\space\text{d}\text{r}=-\frac{\text{G}\text{M}\text{m}}{\text{r}}-\frac{\text{A}\text{m}\text{c}^2\text{r}^2}{6}+\text{K}$$

Where $\text{K}$ is the integration constant.

Comment: Should it not be $-k$?

Comment: @NoahP Why? Because it is a constant

Comment: The negative sign is outside of the integral, so I presume that everything inside the integral should then have its sign reversed?

Comment: @NoahP I understand what you mean, but $-$ a constant or $+$ a constant is just the same thing, it does not change the answer. For the sake when it is a constant you can set $-\text{K}=+\text{K}$